# Alternative for a trigger function in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

Hi I have created a table like `Create table date (id int, mydate date);` and I am using trigger function for inserting an automated date into the table which is like `CREATE TRIGGER add_date BEFORE INSERT ON 'mytable'
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.mydate = NOW();`
. It works fine in wamp server but on a web host it is saying

> "Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation"

Which I think is not possible to use. However, in order to insert automatic date into a table, what I can use as an alternative of the trigger function?

Comment: Application logic. You'll have to move this insert into the application layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a timestamp column to do what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE date (id INT, date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

**Edit:**

AS @Michl stated in the comments:

> "Or, since MySQL 5.6, DATE columns can be automated like this too."

Comment: Or, since MySQL 5.6, `DATE` columns can be automated like this too.

Comment: Thanks you. I didn't knew that. Good to know.

Comment: What about just date? Is it possible to have only date?

Comment: If you use a DATE data type you can with 5.6 and above